Testing for difference in trends of binary-parameter proportion/fraction versus continuous parameter between two (or more) different populations
I have three samples of objects: sample X (total = 138), sample Y (same basic class as X, but located in a different environment; total = 186), and sample Z (total = 996). For each object, I have a measured continuous parameter M and a binomial parameter B (detected or non-detected). Each sample can be considered a random sample from some (much larger) underlying population.
This is a plot of the fraction of objects with B = 1 as a function of M (population X = solid red squares, population Y = open red circles, population Z = smaller blue circles). The bins used are purely for display purposes; as I mentioned, each object has an individual measurement of M, significant to two decimal places.

It seems apparent that populations X and Y show a different trend from population Z, and that populations X and Y shows similar (but not identical?) trends.
What I'm wondering is: is there a way to quantify the statistical significance of the apparent differences or similarities between the trends of the different populations? E.g., under the null hypothesis that two populations have the same underlying trend in fraction(B) versus M, the observed difference can be described with a $P$-value of ...? Can I compare how different from each other samples X and Y are from each other?

Out of curiosity, can you share what M and the environments are? I'm a teacher and I really like this example.

If you are using R, the emmeans package has useful functions for this - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emmeans/versions/1.10.2/topics/emmeans-package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/emmeans.pdf

@FransRodenburg Sure: the objects are disk galaxies of different types/environments (X = S0 galaxies in massive galaxy clusters, Y = S0 galaxies in smaller galaxy groups, Z = spiral galaxies [all environments, but mostly smaller groups]); M = base-10 logarithm of the total stellar mass of the galaxy, in units of the mass of the Sun. The indicator B is whether or not the galaxy has a stellar bar.

An earlier version of just the spiral-galaxy trend (using slightly different estimates of M) can be found in this paper, where I used linear and quadratic logistic regression -- e.g., the red points in FIgure 5.

(In case anyone is curious: our own Milky Way galaxy is a spiral (sample Z) with $M \sim 10.7$ and $B = 1$ -- i.e., it has a bar.)

@PeterErwin Thank you, that's very interesting! I will definitely have a look at your paper

Yes, you could do this by comparing the slopes of a spline for $M$, using a logistic regression model.
Here is an example with some made up data with random trends:
# Simulate some data
require("splines")
set.seed(1)
n1          <- 138 
n2          <- 186 
n3          <- 996
n           <- n1 + n2 + n3
M           <- runif(n, 7.75, 11.25)
Environment <- factor(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), times = c(n1, n2, n3)))
X           <- model.matrix(~ ns(M, 3) * Environment)
beta        <- rnorm(ncol(X))
eta         <- X %*% beta
y           <- rbinom(n, 1, binomial()$linkinv(eta))

DF <- data.frame(M, Environment, y)

# Fit a logistic spline regression model
GLM <- glm(y ~ ns(M, 3) * Environment, family = "binomial", DF)

# Visualization of the model fit
require("sjPlot")
plot_model(GLM, type = "pred", terms = c("M", "Environment"))


Do the spline coefficients differ from each other for different environments?
summary(GLM)
# Call:
# glm(formula = y ~ ns(M, 3) * Environment, family = "binomial", 
#     data = DF)
# 
# Coefficients:
#                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# (Intercept)              0.5276     0.6900   0.765   0.4444  
# ns(M, 3)1                0.9919     0.7540   1.315   0.1884  
# ns(M, 3)2               -0.9268     1.6929  -0.547   0.5841  
# ns(M, 3)3               -1.0596     0.6691  -1.584   0.1133  
# EnvironmentY            -0.8432     0.9345  -0.902   0.3669  
# EnvironmentZ            -0.5329     0.7231  -0.737   0.4611  
# ns(M, 3)1:EnvironmentY  -0.7761     1.0408  -0.746   0.4558  
# ns(M, 3)2:EnvironmentY  -1.1119     2.3335  -0.477   0.6337  
# ns(M, 3)3:EnvironmentY   0.4752     0.9390   0.506   0.6128  
# ns(M, 3)1:EnvironmentZ   2.0611     0.8120   2.538   0.0111 *
# ns(M, 3)2:EnvironmentZ  -0.9048     1.7800  -0.508   0.6112  
# ns(M, 3)3:EnvironmentZ   1.4703     0.7073   2.079   0.0376 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 1812.4  on 1319  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 1628.8  on 1308  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 1652.8
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Here, the interaction terms tell you whether the spline coefficients differ from those of $X$ (the reference group). From here, I would plot the spline basis functions, to see if you can interpret the differences in shape a bit. You could also change the reference group to perform different comparisons if you'd like.

Interesting! OK, I wasn't aware of doing logistic regression using splines, but in retrospect it makes sense that one could. Thanks; I'll see if I can make that work.
